# Varnishstat -1 not show avg

Tags: statistics, varnish, zabbix

Looking for a way to collect from `varnishastat -1` values from columns: avg_10/avg_100/avg_1000

Normally varnishstat work in curses mode, and show columns:

```
Name, Current, Change, Average, Avg_10, Avg_100, Avg_1000
```

BUT IN NONCURESE MODE `varnishastat -1` varnish stat does not show AVg_*

I want to add avg_10 to stats in zabbix. I DON'T WANT TOO USE VALUES FROM COLUMNS Current, Change, Average

https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/varnishstat.html

Answer (score 2):

Varnish only keeps current values of counters and gauges. Average columns are explicitly computed by the `varnishstat` tool when opened in 'curses mode'. If you close and reopen `varnishstat` calculation will start again. Therefore `varnishstat -1` won't be able to give you the data you're looking for.

If using Zabbix (or any other monitoring tool) what you usually want is the current value of counters and gauges. Calculation of averages, deltas, etc. is usually a job for the monitoring tool.